# Ionic 2 Angular2 http post set-cookie

Tags: http, angular, cookies, ionic2

Does anyone know if is possible save cookies after http post login in angular 2? When I check headers in response I can see cookies are there but they wont save to browser and Im not able to access them.

[image]

I also tried access 'set-Cookie' directly but not working.

```
this.http.post(this.serverUrl+"/login/", {data: {email: email, pass: pass}}) 
        .subscribe(res => {

            let headers: Headers = res.headers;
            let cook = headers.getAll('Set-Cookie')); //this is null
```

I will be very very glad for any help I have no idea how to do it and save cookies. Thank you.

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Comment: @balicekt/@Franky - any solution to this?